# Phonegap css background image dpi

Tags: css, html, cordova

I am building a phonegap app for ios and i am having some problems with css image backgrounds. Say for example that i have a div that spans over 100% of the viewport. I want to use real resolution images for pixel perfection.

```
<div class="main"></div>
<style>
.main {
width: 100%
height: 100%;
background: transparent url('640×1136.jpg')
}
</style>
```

So basically i want to display a 640×1136 image as background. But the viewport is always 320px wide making the background image stretched.

Can i somehow make the web view use real pixels instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use background-size attribute:

```
background-size: contain
```

or:

```
background-size: cover
```

You have more information in ["Background-size"](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/)

Answer (score 0):

I have felt similar kind of problem while developing an PhoneGap application.
Try Below Solution.

Add the following meta tag to the HTML.

```
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"target-densitydpi=device-dpi\" />
```

Hope this will help you.